# Tabulate data frame with groupby and size methods

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, series

I have a Pandas dataframe, `out`, that I am computing counts on by the columns, `city` and `raingarden` using the 
following series:

`out.groupby(['city','raingarden']).size()` with the output

`city            raingarden
55405           True             3
Edina           True             7
MInneapolis     True             8
Minneapolis     False         2482
                True           847
Minneapolis     False            2
                True             1
Minneapolis,    True             1
Minneapolis,    False            2
Minneapolsi     False            5
                True             3
Minnepolis      False            4
Minnespolis     False            4
Minnetonka      False            1
                True             2
Minnneapolis    False            5
Mpla            True             3
Mpls            False           22
                True            20
Mpls.           False            8
                True            17
NE Mpls         True             6
Richfield       True             1
SLP             True             3
St Louis Park   True             2
St. Louis Park  False            1
Victoria        False            1
Wayzata         False            2
                True             1
minneapolis     False            3
mpls            True             2
dtype: int64`

I want to take this and output it to a `tabulate` table.

To do this, I did the following:

```
headers = ['city','has rain garden', 'n']
print tabulate(out.groupby(['city','raingarden']).size().to_frame(), headers, tablefmt="simple")
```

Issue 1: I need to get a column name on the counts, but have not had any luck;

Issue 2 (which is probably related to issue 1), the output looks like this:

```
city                          has rain garden
--------------------------  -----------------
(u'55405', True)                            3
(u'Edina', True)                            7
(u'MInneapolis', True)                      8
(u'Minneapolis', False)                  2482
(u'Minneapolis', True)                    847
(u'Minneapolis ', False)                    2
(u'Minneapolis ', True)                     1
(u'Minneapolis,', True)                     1
(u'Minneapolis, ', False)                   2
(u'Minneapolsi', False)                     5
(u'Minneapolsi', True)                      3
(u'Minnepolis', False)                      4
(u'Minnespolis', False)                     4
(u'Minnetonka', False)                      1
(u'Minnetonka', True)                       2
(u'Minnneapolis', False)                    5
(u'Mpla', True)                             3
(u'Mpls', False)                           22
(u'Mpls', True)                            20
(u'Mpls.', False)                           8
(u'Mpls.', True)                           17
(u'NE Mpls', True)                          6
(u'Richfield', True)                        1
(u'SLP', True)                              3
(u'St Louis Park', True)                    2
(u'St. Louis Park', False)                  1
(u'Victoria', False)                        1
(u'Wayzata', False)                         2
(u'Wayzata', True)                          1
(u'minneapolis', False)                     3
(u'mpls', True)                             2
```

The first two columns are given as a tuple? Thus, how do I split these into separate columns, and how do I add a label for my counts? I am sure what I am trying to achieve should be much simpler than I tried.

Comment: Perhaps ``pivot_table`` is what you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315837/groupby-and-pivot-pandas-table

Comment: `.unstack()` the result.

Comment: Can you add `out.head()` to the question so we know what your original data looks like?

Comment: Pivoting the data is definitely not what I need, but I will need it for some other analysis I am doing, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By groping by two columns, you are creating a multi-level index `Series`, which I believe is not what you want. I am not sure how to original data looks like (would be nice providing `out.head()` in the question), but I believe what you are looking for is:

```
out.groupby('city').sum()['raingarden']
```

Here's an example with some randomly generated data:

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

city = random.sample(string.lowercase*500,100)
raingarden = np.random.randint(0,10,100)

out = pd.DataFrame({'city':city, 'raingarden':raingarden})
```

Output:

```
In [30]: out.groupby('city').sum()['raingarden']
Out[30]:
city
a    17
b     7
c    16
d     8
e    24
f    28
g    16
h    49
i    29
j    24
k     4
l     5
m    17
n    29
p    22
q    14
r    19
s     6
t    21
u     8
v    18
w    25
x    11
y     9
z    40
Name: raingarden, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yep, that did it... not sure why I was grouping by the two columns.

Comment: I had to use the count() method, instead, since 'raingarden' was a Boolean. But, this did it.