# Is there a difference between pd.pivot_table() and df.pivot()?

Tags: python, pandas

Because when I do

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='frequency', columns='word', index=['senator', 'state'])
```

I get the correct output

```
[10 rows x 42725 columns]
```

But when I do

```
df.pivot(values='frequency', columns='word', index=['senator', 'state'])
```

I get

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 118158, placement implies 2
```

Here is the shape of my data:

```
        word  frequency  senator state
1   straight          5  daschle    sd
2    screens          1  daschle    sd
3  knockdown          1  daschle    sd
4  Combating          3  daschle    sd
5        say        169  daschle    sd
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://nikolaygrozev.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) page that explain the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Difference between pivot and pivot\_table. Why is only pivot\_table working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960338/pandas-difference-between-pivot-and-pivot-table-why-is-only-pivot-table-workin)