# Converting long format to wide dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this format:

```
Age            Gender Period  Unemployed
16 to 19 years Men   2005-01-01   91000
20 to 24 years Men   2005-01-01   175000
16 to 19 years Women 2005-01-01   88888
20 to 24 years Women 2005-01-01   175000
16 to 19 years Men   2005-02-01   92000
20 to 24 years Men   2005-02-01   175000
```

Now I want to convert it into wide format such as age is index:

```
                2005-01-01     2005-02-01
               Men     Women   Men   Women
Age
16 to 19 years
20 to 24 years
```

I tried using pivot:

```
df.pivot(index="Age", columns=["Period", "Gender"], value="Unemployed")
```

However I get error about duplicate values. But I dont know why should there be limitation for duplicate values here as I dont aggregate anything just reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) setting both `Period` and `Gender` as columns:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Age', columns=['Period' ,'Gender'], values='Unemployed')

Period             2005-01-01         2005-02-01
Gender             Men   Women        Men
Age                                      
16 to 19 years      91000   88888      92000
20 to 24 years     175000  175000     175000
​
```

Comment: Why is pivot not working for this case?

Comment: Pivot does not accept multiple columns @AlexT

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960338/pandas-difference-between-pivot-and-pivot-table-why-is-only-pivot-table-workin) @alex (second answer)